# Is it possible to change the flight itinerary of one ticket on a package deal?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, mexico, vacations

Two of my girlfriends and I are planning an "all inclusive" vacation to Mexico. Unfortunately one of my friends can only come later during the trip. We have not purchased the tickets yet.

Is it possible to change the flight itinerary for one of the passengers?

i.e. We will book a "7-day all inclusive package" deal but one person will come two days later and we will all return at the same time.

Comment: Maybe. Contact whoever is offering the tickets.

Comment: Please specify the cruise ship company and the package name. Otherwise the question is too broad.

Comment: The only reliable source of information for that question is whoever sold you the tickets .

Comment: Having more than one girlfriend is your sake; we don't judge -- but is it really wise to bring two of them with you on the same vacation _together_?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Girlfriends can actually mean girl friends, i.e. friends who are indeed girls.

Answer (score 2):

I have booked a few of these, and unfortunately the package deal means that the flight times are fixed (as rates are seasonal). You may choose to come later but you'll have to pay any differences up-to and including a full fare cost.

If the package is being offered directly by the airline, you have a better chance of changing the flight portion. I did this once - the same package instead of buying it from an agent I bought it directly form the airline and I was able to select two different flight itineraries without any additional penalties - and it ended up being cheaper than the agent's quote.

Bottom line - ask your vacation provider.